# Laravel 5.8: Eloquent Pagination for Bootstrap Datatable

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I couldn't find any questions like this. All other questions are not using the Bootstrap datatables like me - they built their own table.

My Laravel 5.8 application returns currently a list of users in a searchable datatable. The problem is, that it's returning ALL users at once, so the page loads really slow since the application has a lot of users.

My `routes\web.php`:

```php
Route::get('/admin/customers', 'Admin\CustomerController@renderPage')->name('admin.customers');
```

My `app\Http\Controllers\Admin\CustomerController.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts;
use App\User;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function renderPage() {
        $customers = User::get();

        return view('pages.admin.customers')->with([
                'customers' => $customers
            ]);
    }
}
```

My table in the view `resources\views\pages\admin\customers.blade.php` gets generated like this (I've removed the not relevant HTML code):

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Datatables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="customers-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($customers as $customer)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $customer->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $customer->first_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $customer->last_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $customer->email }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Datatables -->
<script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
   // Datatable settings
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#customers-table').DataTable({
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu":   "Show _MENU_ entires per page",
                "search":       "Search:",
                "decimal":      ".",
                "thousands":    ",",
                "zeroRecords":  "No entries found.",
                "info":         "Showing entries _START_ to _END_ of total _TOTAL_",
                "infoEmpty":    "No entries available.",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
                "paginate": {
                    "first":    "First",
                    "last":     "Last",
                    "next":     "Next",
                    "previous": "Previous"
                }
            }
        });
    } );
</script>
```

So the question is: What do I need to update to what in order to add support for pagination?

Comment: I forget how it works, but DataTables should support a server-based approach, where the results are loaded/paginated via an AJAX request. Basically, you wouldn't query for `User` models until DataTables requests it, and you can handle limit/offset (pagination) then.

Comment: Use [laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) to handle DataTables using server-side processing mode.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I ran into the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rendering the html on the server, try to load the DataTable via Ajax.

**HTML**

```html
<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap dataTable no-footer dtr-inline collapsed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>E-Mail</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
const table = $('#customer-table').DataTable({
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': {
        'url': 'customers/list',
        'type': 'POST'
    },
    'columns': [
        {'data': 'id'},
        {'data': 'first_name'},
        {'data': 'last_name'},
        {'data': 'email'},
        {
            'orderable': false,
            'searchable': false,
            'data': null,
            'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                  // render custom html
                  return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>';
            }
        }
    ],
});
```

**PHP**

On the server-side take the POST request parameters and build a dynamic query (with the QueryBuilder).

Then map the result set into a DataTable compatible JSON response:

**The controller action**

```php
// Build dynamic query
// ...

// Fetch result set
// ...

return response()->json([
    'recordsTotal' => $count,
    'recordsFiltered' => $count,
    'draw' => $draw,
    'data' => $rows,
];
```

More details about the json response: [DataTable Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but how can I use `if`-conditions in the table for showing different icons for booleans for example or convert date timestamps using `Carbon`? Because as far as I understood, `<tbody></tbody>` must be empty, right?

Comment: You can format the data on the server-side too. To render custom html on the client-side into a cell, just use the 'render' callback. [More details](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'm still checking out, how my controller needs to look like.